# Django: url in "form action" doesn't work

Tags: django, forms, post

In detail.html:

```
<form id="answer_form" class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'puzzle:update' puzzle.id %}" method="POST" onSubmit="return ValidateAnswer();">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>Please entry your answer below: (Case insensitive)</p>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <input id="player_answer" maxlength="30" name="player_answer" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <button id="submit_answer_btn" class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
function ValidateAnswer() {
    var player_answer = document.getElementById("player_answer");
    if(player_answer.value == {{ puzzle.answer }}) {
        alert("Congratulations!");
    } else {
        alert("Wrong answer!");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

In url.py

```
app_name = 'puzzle'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', login_required(views.PuzzleDetailView.as_view()), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<puzzle_id>[0-9]+)/update/$', views.update_user_game_history, name='update'),
]
```

In views.py

```
class PuzzleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Puzzle
    template_name = 'puzzle/detail.html'


def update_user_game_history(request, puzzle_id):
    player_game_history = PlayerGameHistory.objects.get(user=request.user)
    solved_puzzle = Puzzle.objects.get(id=puzzle_id)
    player_game_history.score += solved_puzzle.point
    player_game_history.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

What I am trying to do is to click on **Submit** button, via 2nd url, go to the **update_user_game_history** function in views.py.

However, everytime I submit, the flow tries to, via 1st url, go to the PuzzleDetailView. And I get **Method Not Allowed (POST): /2/** in terminal

Comment: Please show code for `ValidateAnswer()` javascript function.

Comment: What does the rendered form tag look like (click view source in your browser). Your `{% url %}` tag looks ok to me. Make sure you have saved any open files and restarted your server so that you are definitely running the code you think you are.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that solved your problem but basically in the view you don't have a way to ensure if the method is 'POST' or not. To solve that you can add this line in your code:

```
def update_user_game_history(request, puzzle_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        player_game_history = PlayerGameHistory.objects.get(user=request.user)
        solved_puzzle = Puzzle.objects.get(id=puzzle_id)
        player_game_history.score += solved_puzzle.point
        player_game_history.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

But according with your example is not necessary call a form because you aren't using it. My recommendation is to improve this view because only with a url you can score many times you want

Comment: @jiyi I am glad that helped you, don't forget upvote if you liked or accept it

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Alasdair. After checking the rendered form tag, I found out the problem. Value of action attribute in form tag was wrong. It was still "#". It seems like Chrome back button doesn't retrieve the lastest page from server. It only reload what it received before.